# Cмаппить поле из типа определенным пользователем в cassandra с полем в java

Tags: java, spring-data, cassandra

Как можно смаппить поле из типа определенным пользователем  с полем в java со spring data

```
CREATE TYPE s.prod (
  event_time timestamp
);


 @UserDefinedType("prod")
public class Search {

 @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TIMESTAMP) где писать event_time
 private Date eventTime;
```

Comment: вроде все корректно сделано, в чем возникла проблема ?

Comment: @senior-pomidor то что в типе написано event_time а в java eventTime. Надо как то смапить их, дать понять что это java поле относится к такому полю в типе

Comment: можно конечно написать в java private Date event_time, но так не сойдет

Comment: @senior-pomidor javadoc userTypeName If the property maps to a user-defined type then this attribute holds the user type name. это как раз указываю мой тип к примеру Search пишу. public class Search, указываю тогда userTypeName="search"

Comment: `@Column("event_time)` над полем, не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "event_time")
private Date eventTime;
```